# .NET 6 console app: SQL Server Spatial Library could not be loaded

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, .net-6.0

I have a out of the box - based on the new project template - .NET 6 console application that I have added the nuget package [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/) version `160.1000.6`.

I get the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: SQL Server Spatial library could not be loaded. Error code: 126 (HResult: 0x80131524).
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.ThowIfGLNativeLibraryNotLoaded()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GLNativeMethods.IsValid(GeoData g)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.IsValidExpensive()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.Construct(GeoData g, Int32 srid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.GeometryFromBinary(OpenGisType type, SqlBytes binary, Int32 srid)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB(SqlBytes wkbGeometry, Int32 srid)
> at geometry_tester.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\source\repos\geometry-tester\Program.cs:line 31

My source code is:

```
try
{
    object objectValue = DBNull.Value;

    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("AQMAAAABAAAACwAAAAAAAADqllrAAAAAQHueOEAAAADAZIVawAAAAKDbwjhAAAAAAOF4WsAAAAAgE285QAAAAADnjFrAAAAAAFYaOkAAAAAA6pZawAAAAEBEPjpAAAAAwHnLWsAAAABARD46QAAAAEB70FrAAAAAAFYaOkAAAABAe9BawAAAACATbzlAAAAAwHnLWsAAAACgvC85QAAAAADwqlrAAAAAoNvCOEAAAAAA6pZawAAAAEB7njhA");

    objectValue = (object)SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes(bytes), 4326).MakeValid();

    Console.WriteLine($"Converted Output: {((SqlGeometry)objectValue).ToString()}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
finally 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

with line 31 that is referenced in the error being this line:

```
objectValue = (object)SqlGeometry.STGeomFromWKB(new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes(bytes), 4326).MakeValid();
```

What's extra weird about this problem is I am only experiencing it in one of our environments (Prod of course!), the application code above runs successfully in all my lower environments. So I'm pretty sure I'm running into either an access issue or permissions or some sort of security scanning, but am looking for help in diagnosing. I do not see anything captured in Windows EventViewer pointing to why it thinks it cannot find the spatial library. Our security scanning software that is installed does not show anything in its logs indicating it is preventing access to the library or anything like that.

I did run Systernals ProcMon and do see the process scanning through the application folder looking for `SqlServerSpatial160.dll`, I see it look in the folder in my application in `\runtimes\win-x64\native`. I don't really understand how to read what ProcMon is doing, but it looks like it implies it successfully reads the .dll file, but then continues on trying to find the dll, not finding it, and I assume that leads to the crash.  Running the same ProcMon test in the working environments, it looks like it stops once it lands on the location of the .dll file on the file system.

My published application has my executable, the .NET dependencies, etc. in its root folder. Also in the root folder are `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.dll` and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll`.  The spatial library I assume from nuget is then in a subfolder off the root folder, in a `runtimes` folder which then has a bunch of architecture folders and then eventually the `SqlServerSpatial160.dll` file.

This is obviously some difference in my environments but I'm looking for some further ideas on how to troubleshoot or diagnose *why* it's throwing this error so I can fix it. Running as Administrator makes no difference, and I don't see any obvious differences in things like installed applications, either.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you're supposed to load Native libs, something like Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

Answer (score 0):

Try install **Microsoft SQLSysCLRTypes** on production environment.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=100451

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Realized I never posted what I found to be the issue.  Using ProcMon and an isolated test app to reproduce, I found that the problem environment was missing a DLL, `vcruntime140.dll`, that was present on the other systems.  The fix ended up being to explicitly reinstall the Visual C++ Redistributable that included that DLL, and the issue went away.